# Symfony Routing Host Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, symfony, routes

I have a route in my Symfony project that should be restricted only to hosts that contains a specific word in a subdomain, a domain is not important and it will vary. Lets say this specific word is 'pre', so I want only hosts build like this (pre.anything.com, pre.anything2.co.uk, pre.anything3.us) to access certain route. Is it possible to configure it as such in a symfony routing?

*routes.yaml*

```
base_register:
    path:     /register/
    host:     "/pre/"
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\AppController::registerAction }
```

Using:

- Symfony 4.2
- PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is similar to the docs for subdomains : https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-placeholders

You can use this config:

```
base_register:
    path:     /register/
    host:     "pre.{domain}"
    controller: App\Controller\AppController::register
    defaults:
        domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
        domain: '%domain%'
```

and then in your parameters.yml you define your `domain` param where you set your default domain.

In your domain requirement you can set `(.*)` to catch both domain and subdomain.

Comment: Trying to make it work, but with no results. Configured it just as you said and I get an error "No route found for". When I delete the 'host' option everything works fine. Might the reason be that I try to access this route with subsubdomain (pre.subdomain.domain.com)?

Comment: As a requirement I set (.*) and it started working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to know it's working, I added your comment to my answer. Please accept the answer for people how are having / (will have)  the same issue as you.